# Is it possible to have 3 EditTexts which change each other EditText which are interchangable between all 3?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is in android studio.

So I have 3 edit texts which need to be interchangeable between all 3. They do math so for example let's say they are each labeled editText1, editText2, and editText3. If I were to type a number into editText1 and editText2 it should update editText3. If I were to type a number into editText2 and into editText3 it would update editText1. I then should be able to delete any data between any of the editTexts and change them on the fly without any EditText instances getting locked up. I have been able to change any of them on the get go, but I end up locking it up.

Would it be possible to make them interchangeable without locking at least one EditText up? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by locking up the edittexts, but you could try to use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) to achieve that.

eg.

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }

 @Override
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }

 @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

  //Add the logic necessary to achieve your requirements here

  eg. 

  if(!editText2.getText().toString().isEmpty){
    //Do your math and set the text to editext3
    val value1 = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());
    val value2 = Integer.parseInt(editText2.getText().toString());

    editText3.setText(value1 + value2)

  }

 } 
});
```

and so on....

Answer (score 0):

Here try something like that

```
public class watcher implements TextWatcher {
EditText changeAble;
EditText Effector;
public watcher(EditText otherEffector,EditText otherEditor){
    this.Effector =otherEffector;
    this.changeAble = otherEditor;
}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    //To not change the other editText in case of deleting
    if(!s.toString().isEmpty()){
        changeAble.setText(Integer.valueOf(s)+Integer.valueOf(Effector.getText().toString()));
    }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {



}
```

}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText editText3 = findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    watcher watcher = new watcher(editText2,editText1);
    editText3.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    editText2.addTextChangedListener(new watcher(editText3,editText1));




}
```

}